# Defining a Function in python 3.6 and expecting True or False but returning None

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, boolean

def gender():

Creating a function that should return True or False

```
    gener = input('Choose \"1\" for Male or \"2\" for Female: ')
```

"gener" should receive "1" or "2" as string

```
    if gener == '1':
        print('You selected Male')
        return True
    elif gener == '2':
        print('You selected Female')
        return False
    else:
```

Here happens the problem. It should execute again the function gender() so the user could reinsert "1" or "2" correctly

```
        print('Invalid character')
        gender()
```

But when printing the function gender() it returns "None" even if gender() is executed again in order to receive a new value, continuing with the value of Else statement

```
print(gender())
```

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to recursively call functions unless you really have some recursive algorithm. For your problem, have a look at [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for ideas.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thats an awfully nice post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: `from itertools import repeat, dropwhile; gender = next(dropwhile(lambda x: x not in ('1', '2'),  (input() for _ in repeat(None))))`

Comment: All the code needed to reproduce the error is present in the question. The question is not fully about "How to ask for Input until valid?" but rather about why this codes `returns None` - see answer for why.

Comment: Here is a non-recursive one-liner for you `from itertools import repeat; gender = next(filter(lambda x: x in ('1', '2'), (input() for _ in repeat(None))))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In python every function returns `None` if you do not return anything. Check your `if .. .elif ... else` - where does the `else` return anything?

It does not - it just calls `gender()` (and then implicitly returns `None`)

Change it to return the return of that function call:

```
 if gener == '1':
    print('You selected Male')
    return True
elif gener == '2':
    print('You selected Female')
    return False
else:
    print('Invalid character')
    return gender()
```

This would fix your code, to make it better do not use recursion.

---

Using unneded recursion will pack new data onto call stacks all the time. You can optimize it by using a loop instead of recursing:

```
def gender():
    """Choose Male or Femal, return True for Male and False for Female"""

    gener = ""   # prepare an invalid input
    while gener not in ['1','2']:  # loop until input gets valid
        gener = input('Choose "1" for Male or "2" for Female: ')

    if gener == '1':
        print('You selected Male')
        return True
    # elif gener == '2':
    #    print('You selected Female')
    #    return False
    else: # no need for explicit check, it can only be 1 or 2 
        print('You selected Female')
        return False

print(gender())
```

---

Sidenote for political correctness:

- not all humans on earth term themself as male or female
- not all humans on earth wan't to make this decision known
- gender might change over a livetime

Comment: thanks for the feedback, would have liked to know how to make it better though.